# Запись экрана electron desktopCapturer видит все окна кромне самого себя win10

Tags: electron

Использую стандартно в main.js

```
    desktopCapturer.getSources({
        types: ['window', 'screen'],
      });
```

Electron React Boilerplate

В чём может быть проблема?